# WPF Media Element Video Source

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wmv

I try to set video source in XAML code, video doesn't play:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="bgvideo" Width="800" Height="600"Source="/Videos/BG_LOOP_BIG.wmv" />
```

So I try to set video source in codebehind, that doesn't play too. :

```
bgvideo.Source = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Videos/BG_LOOP_BIG.wmv", UriKind.Absolute);
```

or

```
bgvideo.Source = new Uri(@"/Videos/BG_LOOP_BIG.wmv");
```

It just play when video source is absoulte:

```
bgvideo.Source = new Uri(@"C:\SomeFolder\Videos\BG_LOOP_BIG.wmv");
```

**How can I set video source with relative source?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me. Add LoadedBehavior="Manual"

```
<MediaElement LoadedBehavior="Manual" x:Name="bgvideo" Width="800" Height="600" Source="Videos/BG_LOOP_BIG.wmv" />
```

Then in the code behind you need to play the media

```
bgvideo.Play()
```

You also need to lose the first '/' in the uri.

hth

Comment: I already try this issue :

I set LoadedBehavior="Manual" and Loaded event with "bgvideo_Loaded" event handler. I wrote bgvideo.Play()
 in bgvideo_Loaded method. 

Now;
I removed first '/' and still not working :(

Comment: Have you got the wmv in bin/debug/Videos/?

If you remove the LoadedBehavior attribute it should start playing automatically without the need to call Play().

Comment: There is no Video folder in bin/debug :) I copied that, and it works :) Thank you so much. Why visual studio doesn't copy this folder in bin/debug, do you have any idea?

Comment: If you add a 'Video' folder to the project then pop your video in there and set it's 'Copy to Output' property to 'copy' it'll copy it down to the output folder for you.

Comment: damn. had the same issu since now 2 hours. First I thought it was the codec. When removing first "/" slash Visual Studio 2010 says: error, is not part of the project. But it just works perfect now. Just remove first "/" was my secret. thanks to your post!

Answer (score 2):

```
<MediaElement x:Name="bgvideo" Width="800" Height="600"Source="Videos/BG_LOOP_BIG.wmv" />
```

This is also working, you just have to set the property Copy to output directory of the video file on copy if newer or copy always.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the first slash:

:)

also, as far as I know, Videos cannot be embedded into the assembly.